# Is using "eager beaver" completely benign?

Tags: meaning, connotation

Person A uses the phrase "eager beaver" to mean an enthusiastic person. Person B chuckles. Basically my question boils down to who the weirdo is, so to speak:

- A, because "eager beaver" is outdated and the sexual connotations are too strong to hope that one should understand the "normal" meaning
- B, because "eager beaver" is a perfectly benign phrase with no sexual meanings whatsoever. Anyone who sees sexual connotations in this phrase is simply being immature.

Comment: tee-hee.  In-*your*-end-o. To teenage boys practically any word or phrase can have a sexual meaning to it. Or at least that's what SHE said. etc etc etc. "Eager beaver" is funny to teenage boys because "beaver" is a common slang for "vagina", hence why "eager beaver" is so unbearably hilarious.

Comment: Beavers, by the way, are not only "enthusiastic" but they are industrious, hardworking, intelligent, adaptable, resourceful, and a whole lot more!  They can do extensive property damage through their dam building and the subsequent flooding caused by their dams.  They have also been known to attack humans.  A man in Belarus was killed by a beaver recently.  The animal severed an artery in the man's leg, and the man had bled to death by the time his friends got him to a medic.

Comment: @Matt: I'd say that anyone who giggles at such a benign expression is off in another world... probably Uranus ;^)

Comment: For all the eagerness, have you *looked* for some definitions, usage notes anywhere? Where's the *homework*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There cannot be a definitive answer in these kind of usage question, but here's some elements for an answer that is neither your A or B:

- It's still a rank in the scout organisation;
- In [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eager%20beaver), there's no mention of a sexual tone (whereas it
  mentions the vulgar possible use of "beaver");
- In the [Urban dictionnary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eager%20Beaver), only one out of six definitions
  contains a sexual reference for this idiom.  Although it might makes
  some "[grammarian](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grammarian)" cringe, I found this later source  useful  for
  slang, vulgar neologisms and trendy, urban & edgy  words or
  expressions. Anything I don't get in a pop a rap song I can usually
  found there.  The fact that the Urban dictionnary is usually  biased
  toward the dirtier option betwween possible meanings for a word seem
  to indicates, a contrario, that "eager beaver" still retains some
  innocence.

In short: It's still used  without sexual innuendo but  sometimes with one.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, I've never heard this term used other than in a totally innocuous way.

**[Chambers](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/)** gives this as the only meaning:

> **eager beaver** ***noun***, *colloq* someone who is exceptionally enthusiastic or willing

**[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eager?q=eager+beaver#eager)** also gives only a similar innocuous definition

So here, it either retains only its innocuous meaning and/or I'm not up-to-date with the youth culture (which is certainly true!).